# Option<Rc<RefCell<>>> dereferencing problem

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and facing problem trying to browse dynamic tree. In the example below I want to traverse all the nodes, starting from the given one and check for specific value.

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

pub struct TreeNode {
    pub value: i32,
    pub parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {

    pub fn check(&self, val: i32) -> bool {
        let mut curr = &self.parent;
        while let Some(p) = curr {
            if val == p.borrow().value {
                return true;
            }
            curr = &p.borrow().parent;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

pub fn main () {
    let node1 = TreeNode {
        value: 1,
        parent: None
    };
    let boxed_node1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(node1));

    let node2 = TreeNode {
        value: 2,
        parent: Some(boxed_node1.clone())
    };
    let boxed_node2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(node2));
    
    let result = boxed_node2.borrow().check(42);
    println!("result = {result}");
}
```

The compiler gives an error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
12 |         while let Some(p) = curr {
   |                             ---- borrow later used here
...
16 |             curr = &p.borrow().parent;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                     |
   |                     creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Please help me to fix the check() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `curr` holding a reference, you can clone the `Rc` and hold that instead. Here, I've done that while the `Rc` is still inside the `Option`. Since `self` isn't inside `Rc`, I've handled the first iteration separately.

```rust
pub fn check(&self, val: i32) -> bool {
    if val == self.value {
        return true;
    }

    let mut curr = self.parent.clone();
    while let Some(p) = curr {
        if val == p.borrow().value {
            return true;
        }
        curr = p.borrow().parent.clone();
    }
    
    false
}
```